# ruby function returns different boolean value in irb vs repl.it

Tags: ruby, primes, irb

I have written the following function to check if a number is prime:

```
def is_prime?(number)
  arr = (2..number).to_a.select {|m| number % m == 0}
  arr.length == 1 ? true : false
end
```

When passing 4 or 9 as the number in irb, it correctly returns false. However, in [repl.it](https://repl.it/Br7y/452) these evaluate to true.

Here is the test code I am running on repl.it:

```
puts("\nTests for #is_prime?")
puts("===============================================")
puts('is_prime?(2) == true: ' + (is_prime?(2) == true).to_s)
puts('is_prime?(3) == true: ' + (is_prime?(3) == true).to_s)
puts('is_prime?(4) == false: ' + (is_prime?(4) == false).to_s)
puts('is_prime?(9) == false: ' + (is_prime?(9) == false).to_s)
puts("===============================================")
```

And its output:

```
Tests for #is_prime?
===============================================
is_prime?(2) == true: true
is_prime?(3) == true: true
is_prime?(4) == false: true
is_prime?(9) == false: true
===============================================
What could be causing this variation?
```

Comment: Could you "share" your repl.it session? Here is what I am seeing. https://repl.it/Ck9M/0

Comment: Here is the link to my repl.it session:

https://repl.it/Br7y/452

Comment: Your repl is working as expected. Even though 4 and 9 evaluate to true, that is because you are checking that they are false. false == false is true

Comment: I've added the code and output from your repl to the question, and also a link to the repl.  I did that because SO expects questions to stand on their own, without having to read the comments (the comments can be deleted at any time, actually).

Answer (score 2):

I tried on repl.it and I get false for both 4 and 9.

Anyway, two small improvements to your code: - you can call `select` directly on the range, without turn it in an array
- you can return the value of expression itself, without specify true and false

```
def is_prime?(number)
  arr = (2..number).select {|m| number % m == 0}
  arr.length == 1
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have been confused by the output of your test, which is reporting both the expected result of the function, and the alctual result of the function was correct (that is, was what the test expected):

```
is_prime?(2) == true: true
is_prime?(3) == true: true
is_prime?(4) == false: true
is_prime?(9) == false: true
                  ^      ^
                  |      |
                  |      true if the test passed; false if failed
                  |
                  What the function should have returned
```

If the rightmost column contains all "true" values, then the function has passed all of its tests.